# Mapping one block of HTML to another with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a div with multiple images that needs to get replaced by a `<ul>` block that contains an `<li>` for each image. So block 1, below,  needs to get replaced by block 2.

```
Block1

       <div id="box">
           <img src="images/pic1.jpg">
           <img src="images/pic2.jpg">
           <img src="images/pic3.jpg">
                     etc.  
        </div>



 Block2

       <ul>
           <li>
               <img src="images/pic1.jpg">
           </li>
           <li>
                <img src="images/pic2.jpg">
           </li>
           <li>
                <img src="images/pic3.jpg">
           </li>
                           etc.
       </ul>
```

I've started with:

```
$('<ul id='wrapper'>);  
$('#box').find('img').each(function() {  
                src = $(this).find('img')[0]; 
                $('<li><img src=src></li>).appendTo('ul#wrapper') ; 
                 });
```

but this seems clumsy and unlikely to work, and I'm thinking that there must be a more elegant way to pull this off.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way would be to:

```
$('#box').find('img').each(function() {  
    $(this).wrap( "<li></li>" );
});
$('#box').wrapInner( "<ul id='wrapper'></ul>");
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lvyy4p7/)

If you wanted to, you can even add classes and such to your wrap. More details [here](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).